# Is there csf setting to block ip that require certain amount of requests?

Tags: whm

Is there CSF setting that would help me block certain IP's if they hit homepage to many times. 
We are under attack and I see some IP's doing 300 - 4000 requests. Is there easier way to block those with CSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set PORTFLOOD in the server. Try this and make changes in your csf.conf file

By dafualt

> PORTFLOOD = ""

Change that to

> PORTFLOOD = "80;tcp;20;5"

This means that if an IP is making 20 connections to port 80 in 5 seconds, Then csf will block that IP for at least 5 second after the last connection seen.

There will be a mandatory 5 second block before the block is lifted.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to make a sense on how many connections a normal user makes. We are hit pretty hard by a bootnet and hundreds of ip's are just poring in on homepage

Comment: Actually if a visitor loaded your page remotely, He may take multiple connections not 1/user. It depends on type of your website. If he clicks on a link and if that triggers any script, Then there is high chance of more connections. You need to consult with your developer to decide the threshold for connection limit, otherwise the csf will "hurt" your business. :)